# Read Json Object Using PHP

Tags: php, json

I am trying to read a json object using php as follows

```
$jsonObject = file_get_contents("http://10.12.12.189:9080/NonMotorServices/CommonServices.svc/FetchCurrency");      
        $jsonres = json_decode($jsonObject, true);
```

Following are the content of the object

```
{"Data":"[{\"CurrencySymbol\":\"AU$\",\"CurrencyDescription\":\"Austrailian Dollar\",\"CurrencyRate\":135.42,\"CurrencyType\":\"AUD\",\"RequestDate\":\"\\\/Date(1408041000000)\\\/\",\"PolicyId\":\"\",\"QuotationId\":0,\"SellingRate\":135.42},{\"CurrencySymbol\":\"£.\",\"CurrencyDescription\":\"British pound sterling\",\"CurrencyRate\":212.62,\"CurrencyType\":\"GBP\",\"RequestDate\":\"\\\/Date(1408041000000)\\\/\",\"PolicyId\":\"\",\"QuotationId\":0,\"SellingRate\":212.62},{\"CurrencySymbol\":\"EURO\",\"CurrencyDescription\":\"Euro\",\"CurrencyRate\":171.2,\"CurrencyType\":\"EUR\",\"RequestDate\":\"\\\/Date(1408041000000)\\\/\",\"PolicyId\":\"\",\"QuotationId\":0,\"SellingRate\":171.2},{\"CurrencySymbol\":\"¥.\",\"CurrencyDescription\":\"Japanese yen\",\"CurrencyRate\":1.6809,\"CurrencyType\":\"JPY\",\"RequestDate\":\"\\\/Date(1408041000000)\\\/\",\"PolicyId\":\"\",\"QuotationId\":0,\"SellingRate\":1.6809},{\"CurrencySymbol\":\"SIN$\",\"CurrencyDescription\":\"Singapore Dollar\",\"CurrencyRate\":107.3,\"CurrencyType\":\"SGD\",\"RequestDate\":\"\\\/Date(1408041000000)\\\/\",\"PolicyId\":\"\",\"QuotationId\":0,\"SellingRate\":107.3},{\"CurrencySymbol\":\"Rs.\",\"CurrencyDescription\":\"Sri Lankan Rupees\",\"CurrencyRate\":1,\"CurrencyType\":\"LKR\",\"RequestDate\":\"\\\/Date(1408041000000)\\\/\",\"PolicyId\":\"\",\"QuotationId\":0,\"SellingRate\":1},{\"CurrencySymbol\":\"CHF\",\"CurrencyDescription\":\"Swiss Frank\",\"CurrencyRate\":141.71,\"CurrencyType\":\"CHF\",\"RequestDate\":\"\\\/Date(1408041000000)\\\/\",\"PolicyId\":\"\",\"QuotationId\":0,\"SellingRate\":141.71},{\"CurrencySymbol\":\"US$.\",\"CurrencyDescription\":\"United States dollar\",\"CurrencyRate\":135,\"CurrencyType\":\"USD\",\"RequestDate\":\"\\\/Date(1408041000000)\\\/\",\"PolicyId\":\"\",\"QuotationId\":0,\"SellingRate\":137}]","ID":1}
```

I need to list down currency in a html selection and i used following to do so.

```
echo '<select>';
foreach($jsonres->Data as $option)
    {    echo '<option value=' . $option->CurrencyDescription . '>' . $option->CurrencyDescription . '</option>';  
}
echo '</select>';
```

I am getting an empty selection as a result and i need to load 'CurrencyDescription ' as option value. Please help me with this. and please explain what is the error i made because i am  new to php and json.

Full Code as follows

```
     <?php

        $jsonObject = file_get_contents("http://10.12.12.189:9080/NonMotorServices/CommonServices.svc/FetchCurrency");      
        $jsonres = json_decode($jsonObject, true);

 echo '<select>';
foreach($jsonres->Data as $option)
    {    echo '<option value=' . $option->CurrencyDescription . '>' . $option->CurrencyDescription . '</option>';  
}
echo '</select>';


           ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I Solve The Problem. Here is My Solution

```
 <select>    
         <?php
        $jsonObject = file_get_contents("http://10.12.12.189:9080/NonMotorServices/CommonServices.svc/FetchCurrency");
    $jsonres = json_decode($jsonObject,true);               
        $val = $jsonres['Data'];      
$phpArray = json_decode($val, true);
foreach ($phpArray as $key => $value) {
    $curName;
    foreach ($value as $k => $v) { 
        if($k === 'CurrencyDescription'){ 
        $curName=$v;}

    }
    echo '<option value=' . $curName. '>' . $curName. '</option>'; 
}

           ?>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 2):

`$jsonres` is actually an array.

This is because `true` is being passed as the second parameter to `json_decode`. If you, in fact, do want `$jsonres` to be an object, then just use `json_decode($jsonObject);`.

An easy way to check what your variable contains is to use the `var_dump` function.

```
$jsonres = json_decode($jsonObject);
var_dump($jsonres);
```

Also, be sure you have [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) turned on and set to E_ALL. The following code, `$jsonres->Data`, should be causing PHP to emit a "PHP Notice".