# PHP array to html selection

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here is my array

```
[{"CurrencySymbol":"AU$","CurrencyDescription":"Austrailian Dollar","CurrencyRate":135.42,"CurrencyType":"AUD","RequestDate":"\/Date(1408041000000)\/","PolicyId":"","QuotationId":0,"SellingRate":135.42},{"CurrencySymbol":"£.","CurrencyDescription":"British pound sterling","CurrencyRate":212.62,"CurrencyType":"GBP","RequestDate":"\/Date(1408041000000)\/","PolicyId":"","QuotationId":0,"SellingRate":212.62},{"CurrencySymbol":"EURO","CurrencyDescription":"Euro","CurrencyRate":171.2,"CurrencyType":"EUR","RequestDate":"\/Date(1408041000000)\/","PolicyId":"","QuotationId":0,"SellingRate":171.2},{"CurrencySymbol":"¥.","CurrencyDescription":"Japanese yen","CurrencyRate":1.6809,"CurrencyType":"JPY","RequestDate":"\/Date(1408041000000)\/","PolicyId":"","QuotationId":0,"SellingRate":1.6809},{"CurrencySymbol":"SIN$","CurrencyDescription":"Singapore Dollar","CurrencyRate":107.3,"CurrencyType":"SGD","RequestDate":"\/Date(1408041000000)\/","PolicyId":"","QuotationId":0,"SellingRate":107.3},{"CurrencySymbol":"Rs.","CurrencyDescription":"Sri Lankan Rupees","CurrencyRate":1,"CurrencyType":"LKR","RequestDate":"\/Date(1408041000000)\/","PolicyId":"","QuotationId":0,"SellingRate":1},{"CurrencySymbol":"CHF","CurrencyDescription":"Swiss Frank","CurrencyRate":141.71,"CurrencyType":"CHF","RequestDate":"\/Date(1408041000000)\/","PolicyId":"","QuotationId":0,"SellingRate":141.71},{"CurrencySymbol":"US$.","CurrencyDescription":"United States dollar","CurrencyRate":135,"CurrencyType":"USD","RequestDate":"\/Date(1408041000000)\/","PolicyId":"","QuotationId":0,"SellingRate":137}]
```

i need to show 'CurrencySymbol' values in a HTML selection and I am using PHP. please help because i am new to PHP.

Below is what i tried. it is giving only an empty selection

```
     $jsonres = '[{"CurrencySymbol":"AU$","CurrencyDescription":"Austrailian Dollar","CurrencyRate":135.42,"CurrencyType":"AUD","RequestDate":"\/Date(1408041000000)\/","PolicyId":"","QuotationId":0,"SellingRate":135.42},
            {"CurrencySymbol":"£.","CurrencyDescription":"British pound sterling","CurrencyRate":212.62,"CurrencyType":"GBP","RequestDate":"\/Date(1408041000000)\/","PolicyId":"","QuotationId":0,"SellingRate":212.62},
            {"CurrencySymbol":"EURO","CurrencyDescription":"Euro","CurrencyRate":171.2,"CurrencyType":"EUR","RequestDate":"\/Date(1408041000000)\/","PolicyId":"","QuotationId":0,"SellingRate":171.2},
            {"CurrencySymbol":"¥.","CurrencyDescription":"Japanese yen","CurrencyRate":1.6809,"CurrencyType":"JPY","RequestDate":"\/Date(1408041000000)\/","PolicyId":"","QuotationId":0,"SellingRate":1.6809},
            {"CurrencySymbol":"SIN$","CurrencyDescription":"Singapore Dollar","CurrencyRate":107.3,"CurrencyType":"SGD","RequestDate":"\/Date(1408041000000)\/","PolicyId":"","QuotationId":0,"SellingRate":107.3},
            {"CurrencySymbol":"Rs.","CurrencyDescription":"Sri Lankan Rupees","CurrencyRate":1,"CurrencyType":"LKR","RequestDate":"\/Date(1408041000000)\/","PolicyId":"","QuotationId":0,"SellingRate":1},
            {"CurrencySymbol":"CHF","CurrencyDescription":"Swiss Frank","CurrencyRate":141.71,"CurrencyType":"CHF","RequestDate":"\/Date(1408041000000)\/","PolicyId":"","QuotationId":0,"SellingRate":141.71},
            {"CurrencySymbol":"US$.","CurrencyDescription":"United States dollar","CurrencyRate":135,"CurrencyType":"USD","RequestDate":"\/Date(1408041000000)\/","PolicyId":"","QuotationId":0,"SellingRate":137}]';

        // var_dump( $jsonres['Data']);         
 echo '<select>';
foreach($jsonres->Data as $option){
echo '<option value=' . $option->CurrencySymbol. '>' . $option->CurrencySymbol. '</option>';  
 }
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: What have you tried already? Paste some code and we can point you to the right direction. `foreach` would be a good starting point to try.

Comment: Please explain in brief

Comment: You can't just come here and ask someone to write your code for you. Please show what you have tried and what isn't working for you. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `$obj=json_decode($yourStringAbove); echo $obj->CurrencySymbol;`

Comment: Duplicate of your own previous question, [Read Json Object Using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25320969/read-json-object-using-php)

Answer (score 1):

You need to decode the json data first.
Use: `$jsonres = json_decode( $jsonres );`

Then:

```
foreach ($jsonres as $key => $value) {
echo '<option value=' . $value->CurrencySymbol. '>' . $value->CurrencySymbol. '</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my comment on your initial question, i will not write the code for you as you did not even try to do it yourself first.

But what you need to do is decode the json and then loop through that array outputting the currency symbol in a html select.

Comment: Sorry for not putting my code earlier. I just edited my question and now you can see what i have tried

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like...

```
foreach( $this->currency_array as $key => $value) {
    echo $value['CurrencySymbol'];
}
```

where...

$currency_array = *your array*